Creep mechanism (thermal and irradiation induced/enhanced) and embrittlement in fcc and bcc
When comparing FCC (Face-Centered Cubic) and BCC (Body-Centered Cubic) metals, I typically consider their packing efficiency and the number of active slip planes. FCC structures exhibit higher packing efficiency and a greater number of active slip planes compared to BCC structures.
From various sources, I have learned that thermal creep is more pronounced in FCC metals. I attribute this to the higher number of active slip systems in FCC, which facilitates dislocation glide, leading to creep deformation.
Additionally, I’ve read that BCC metals exhibit a more significant presence of induced/enhanced creep. Induced creep in BCC is associated with the formation of dislocation loops, while enhanced creep is related to the climb motion of dislocations. I reasoned that this enhanced creep behavior in BCC could be due to its lower packing efficiency, which allows for higher diffusivity and, consequently, greater defect mobility.
Regarding embrittlement, some sources suggest that helium embrittlement is more pronounced in FCC metals, possibly due to the presence of nickel and the (n,α) reaction. On the other hand, neutron embrittlement is reported to be more significant in BCC metals. I hypothesize that this is because the fewer slip planes in BCC structures make it easier for defects to obstruct dislocation movement, thereby contributing to embrittlement.
Are my explanations correct?
It is very difficult to find information about this online and in books. I studied on Olander book but still some things are not that clear to me. I usually try to use logic to justify things but I'm not sure my reasoning are correct. thank you deeply in advance for your help.

This is way too broad of a question - details will matter for any given alloy and environment. As one example, there are many fcc metals that have no nickel in them. For things I've worked on the main source of He is alpha particles.

actually this was just a qualitative question and related to crystallographic structure.
